# Twilio: How to check if Account SID & Auth token are valid

Tags: php, twilio

I am developing a project where users can insert their Twilio Account SID & Auth token and then make call and sms.

But how can I verify the Account SID and Auth token using php?

Comment: I've corrected your spelling; you can make this question even better by explaining what you found yourself so-far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API test specifically for this. You get the information from the website:

```
 https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/what-is-the-auth-token-and-how-can-i-change-it

 check like this: 
 $client = new Pricing_Services_Twilio($sid, $token); 
    $country = $client->phoneNumberCountries->get("US");
    print_r($country->phone_number_prices);die;
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than encouraging your users to share their auth token, effectively their password, you could use [Twilio Connect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/connect). It's an OAuth like flow that returns you the user's account sid and an auth token that only you can use to access the account.

This saves users' sharing their auth tokens and guarantees you a valid Account Sid and Auth Token that you can use.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this advice, but I don't see Connect Apps anywhere. My account is not a trial, is this feature still supported?

Comment: It's still supported, you can find it under the [Twilio Runtime in your console](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/connect-apps).

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token); print_r($client->voiceCountries);
```

if your sid invalid it will return error, but if valid it will show all country list of twilio number